# No Eclipse versions will install

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, installation

Trying to install *any version* of Eclipse will fail with varying errors.

Sometimes I get the error: [image: installer error]
with error log

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2019-02-19 19:49:23.951
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Control.internal_new_GC(Control.java:2180)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(GC.java:177)
    at org.eclipse.swt.graphics.GC.<init>(GC.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.jface.dialogs.Dialog.initializeDialogUnits(Dialog.java:937)
```

[here](https://pastebin.com/vN8m7GkK).

Other times I open the installer and I get a window with dialog boxes that are messed up [image: messed up graphics]
clicking on the visible box gives this error [image: messed up graphics error] (text [here](https://pastebin.com/TDyRFGmL)).  (Note: This only happens when I have an older version of Eclipse running).

Downloading an older version of Eclipse isn't helpful either.  Trying to install Neon gives [this](https://pastebin.com/index.php?e=1) error.  It mentions something about a `ImageBuilderInternalException` on something called `MattStuff`, but it's not the only type of error and I have no clue where this `MattStuff` is so I may delete it.

Trying to install Neon now gives [another error](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s_dwLtDucGJkqr5raqtXnZuIe_kPE4k8/view?usp=sharing)

Trying to get Mars gives [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h7dmsCl2O_KTVxky0kVTC0jjLOOPEUHy/view?usp=sharing) error.

Trying to directory get the Eclipse application instead of the Eclipse Installer (as suggested by @howlger) gives these errors.  Note: Clicking on details does not do anything.

[image: Trying to open Eclipse]
[image: Clicking Launch takes me here]
[image: Trying to create a file gives me this error]

Comment: DId you try using different java version when the error occurs?

Comment: What version of the O.S. is this? Which versions of the JDK do you have installed? Only the most recent releases are compatible with JDK 11, have you tried the 2018-12 version?

Comment: Obviously, not installing Eclipse but running the _Eclipse Installer_ fails. The reason could be that you are running an outdated version of the _Eclipse Installer_ with Java 11.0.1, which is not possible. Try to [directly install an Eclipse 2018-12 package](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/) instead of using the _Eclipse Installer_.

Comment: @nitind I am running the latest version of macOS.  I believe this is JDK 11 
`javac --version`
`javac 11.0.1`

Comment: @howlger thank you.  Please see my updated post

Comment: @MaxCoplan Where and how did you install the `*.dmg` file? Did you open an existing workspace? Which error message do you get exactly? Does `~/.eclipse` exist and is it writeable?